# Already initialized constant warnings after Rails 4.2 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, rails-postgresql

After upgrading a simple Rails 4.1.8 application to Rails 4.2.0, I see lots of warnings about already initialized constants coming out of the PostgreSQL adapter:

```
/path/to/my/torquebox-3.1.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/array_parser.rb:6 warning: already initialized constant DOUBLE_QUOTE
/path/to/my/torquebox-3.1.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/array_parser.rb:7 warning: already initialized constant BACKSLASH
/path/to/my/torquebox-3.1.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/array_parser.rb:8 warning: already initialized constant COMMA
/path/to/my/torquebox-3.1.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/array_parser.rb:9 warning: already initialized constant BRACKET_OPEN
/path/to/my/torquebox-3.1.1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/array_parser.rb:10 warning: already initialized constant BRACKET_CLOSE
```

Is this expected or does it indicate a problem with the new version of Rails (presumably running under JRuby)? Any way to properly fix these warnings (other than just silencing them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by the **activerecord-jdbc-adapter** gem which includes some of the core AR functionality, since it supports multiple AR releases from a single AR-JDBC gem release.

Due changes in ActiveRecord's PostgreSQL adapter support it seems to double load `ArrayParser`. Please note that supporting Rails 4.2 requires work [here](https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues/599) and/or [here](https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues/572).

Answer (score 1):

Known issue with very little discussion referenced here:  https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/2286 .

When it is solved there may be an update at that location.